# iOS Framework Tests fail in Xcode Workspace

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest

I have an Xcode workspace containing 2 Swift projects, OAuth and Commons.
Each project has an iOS framework target and a Test target. They do not depend on each other.
The **Commons** project has **no dependencies** while the **OAuth** framework target **imports WebKit** (`import  WebKit`).

Now, if I run the tests in Xcode the OAuth tests work fine but the Commons tests fail with the following Xcode error log:

```
Test target CommonsTests encountered an error (Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted)
```

If I run the test from the command line with the following commands

```
xcodebuild -workspace Workspace.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6" -scheme OAuth test

xcodebuild -workspace Workspace.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6" -scheme Commons test
```

I get the following error after the second command:

```
The bundle “CommonsTests” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources. Try reinstalling the bundle.
(dlopen_preflight(~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Workspace-aslcnsaomwggxqcxoozzfuztgszf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CommonsTests.xctest/CommonsTests): Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftWebKit.dylib
Referenced from: ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Workspace-aslcnsaomwggxqcxoozzfuztgszf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/OAuth.framework/OAuth Reason: image not found)
```

What could be the problem with my setting?
Does the problem also occur for anybody else?

---

**Workarounds:**

1) If I also include WebKit in the CommonsTests bundle everything works fine. 
But since there is no dependency between the OAuth and the Commons frameworks I can't see any reason why this should be necessary.

2) If I rename the OAuth project (and the target) to something like OAuth2 everything works fine.
This is really odd. Could be either a name clash or a caching issue.

Does the renaming workaround solve the problem for anybody else?

---

Sample project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dn3ywhxlc9kb6y4/SampleProject.zip?dl=0

Setting:
Xcode 7.3   (error occurs on Xcode 7.2 too)
OS X 10.11.4 (error occurs on OS X 10.11.3 too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the issue again, I could find the reason for the strange behaviour.

**Short Answer:**
There is a private OAuth Apple Framework located at `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OAuth.framework/OAuth` which causes a name clash with my own OAuth framework because `xctest` seems to link this framework.

**Long Answer:**
`xctest` or `XCTest.framework` seem to load an OAuth.framework from the Private Frameworks folder.

If one uses a workspace within Xcode, the test environment uses the following environment variable for dyld:

`"DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH“ = "/Users/{USER}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{PROJECT}/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks“;`

The variable has the following effects:

```
DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH
              This is a colon separated list of directories that contain  frameworks.   The  dynamic  linker
              searches  these  directories  before  it  searches  for the framework by its install name.  It
              allows you to test new versions of existing frameworks. (A framework is a library install name
              that  ends  in the form XXX.framework/Versions/YYY/XXX or XXX.framework/XXX, where XXX and YYY
              are any name.)

              For each framework that a program uses, the dynamic linker looks for  the  framework  in  each
              directory  in  DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH  in turn. If it looks in all the directories and can't find
              the framework, it searches the directories in DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH in turn.  If  it  still  can't
              find   the   framework,   it   then   searches   DYLD_FALLBACK_FRAMEWORK_PATH  and  DYLD_FALL-BACK_LIBRARY_PATH DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH
              BACK_LIBRARY_PATH in turn.
```

`DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH` defines the search directories for Frameworks and **overrides** the default search paths and the install names, which embedded into the depending binary. Even if a binary specifies a framework install path like
​`/System/Library/Frameworks/OAuth`
the environment variable leads to the behaviour that the directory
`/Users/{USER}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{PROJECT}/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator`
is searched for an `​OAuth.framework/OAuth` binary regardless of the actual install name.

This behaviour is intended since it allows for overriding Frameworks in an existing binary with newer versions without the need to recompile the binary.

However, it can also entail misleading linking of binaries if two Frameworks have to same names. Then, one of the Frameworks with the same name could be loaded even if the other one is specified by path. If the directory of the first one is contained in the `DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH` either prior to the other one’s directory or at all, then the first one is picked because of its name and regardless of the specified install name path.

**Concrete Example:**

xctest binary load command:
`​/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OAuth.framework/OAuth (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 1280.24.0)`

OAuth is present at the following paths:
`/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OAuth.framework/OAuth`
`/Users/{USER}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{PROJECT}/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/OAuth.framework/OAuth`

xctest is started with the following environment variable:
`"DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH“ = "/Users/{USER}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{PROJECT}/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks“;`

Then the OAuth Framework at
`/Users/{USER}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{PROJECT}/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/OAuth.framework/OAuth`
is used even if the install name is
`/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OAuth.framework/OAuth`